# Using Google Earth to figure out the coordinate reference system from only lon, lat information

Tags: latitude-longitude, google-earth, epsg, plotting

Lately, I've been trying to use lat/long information to plot on QGIS without any good results because I lack the correct EPSG code for the coordinate reference system. This is not the case with Google Earth, which always plots in the correct places using lat/long information.

I concluded that Google has an automatic way to discern them an select the correct coordinate reference system, and other posts have also suggested it. Is there a way to know which one are they using for my data?

```
45.801417207831314,9.092656559575259
45.801417207831314,9.092656559575259
45.801417207831314,9.092656559575259
45.801417207831314,9.092656559575259
45.801421972667725,9.092675509431874
45.80142711235822,9.092700934521718
45.8014346957649,9.09272071353453
45.80144571424553,9.092746763378287
```

Note: my data is from Como, Italy.

Comment: By definition, you can't determine datum by coordinate value. You need a known set of locations.

Comment: in general you should use epsg:4326 for lat/lon data unless you have more information for the datum

Comment: if your data is plotted in the wrong place it is most likely due incorrect axis order, so QGIS thinks your data is lon/lat instead of the lat/lon that it is

Answer (score -1):

Google Earth uses EPSG:4326 (WGS84).  If you put coordinates into Google Earth and they look correct, then they are probably EPSG:4326.

And as one comment mentioned, do check your lat,lon vs lon,lat order.  In Google Earth a KML with a Point will use lon,lat (eg: 3.028,54.825 for a point in the North Sea) in the KML itself, but the search bar in Google Earth expects the reverse and more common order of lat,lon (eg: (eg: 54.825,3.028). Most other software will also use lat,lon.

Comment: Google Earth doesn't use EPSG:4326, which is Lat/Long.  The  KML standard defines it's own CRS ~ https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html#kml_crs_def